# How can I get lines to join up using PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{book}[12pt]

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\psmatrix[colsep=.3cm,rowsep=.5cm,mnode=r]
    [mnode=circle] 1 && && [mnode=circle] 3 \\
    & ~ && ~ \\
    [mnode=circle] 2 && && [mnode=circle] 4 \\
    \ncline{1,1}{2,2}\tlput{$\tau_{1}$}
    \ncline{2,2}{3,1}\tlput{$\tau_{2}$}
    \ncline{2,2}{2,4}\taput{$\tau_{1234}$}
    \ncline{2,4}{1,5}\trput{$\tau_{3}$}
    \ncline{2,4}{3,5}\trput{$\tau_{4}$}
    \endpsmatrix
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am processing the file through LaTeX -> PS -> PDF.

It does exactly what I want it to do except the horizontal line doesn't quite line up to the other lines.

Comment: You should use `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`, not `\documentclass{book}[12pt]`...

Comment: Why's that? I've pretty much learnt LaTeX on the fly.

Comment: That's how it is. While it does work, providing an optional argument *after* the `\documentclass{<class>}` it should typically represent a date, not a point-size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of supplying `~` (a tie or non-breaking space; it has width), use an empty group `{}` for your nodes in the second row (columns 2 and 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \psmatrix[colsep=3mm,rowsep=.5cm,mnode=r]
    [mnode=circle] 1 &    &&    & [mnode=circle] 3 \\
                     & {} && {} & \\
    [mnode=circle] 2 &    &&    & [mnode=circle] 4 \\
    \ncline{1,1}{2,2}\tlput{$\tau_{1}$}
    \ncline{2,2}{3,1}\tlput{$\tau_{2}$}
    \ncline{2,2}{2,4}\taput{$\tau_{1234}$}
    \ncline{2,4}{1,5}\trput{$\tau_{3}$}
    \ncline{2,4}{3,5}\trput{$\tau_{4}$}
  \endpsmatrix
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```